# How can you solve this cubic equation containing decimal $2\pi=3+2t-0.1t^3$?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

I am reading Calculus Made Easy by Silvanus P. Thompson and in one exercise, we have to first solve for this cubic equation but I am a bit lost on what to do, I think the $\pi$ throws me off.

We have to solve for a full rotation in the equation
$\Theta=3+t2-0.1t^3$

$2\pi=3+2t-0.1t^3$

I rearrange the term:
$0.1t^3-2t-3+2\pi=0$

$0.1t^3-2t+3.2831=0$

In the book, he gets 2.11 and 3.02 and a third negative value but I don't know how he arrives there.
Finding common factors of the constant and the leading coefficient or dividing all terms by 0.1 seem to lead me nowhere. Anyone can help solving this?

Comment: Use a graphing calculator.

Comment: The values Thompson gets are *approximations*, and there are any number of ways to get approximations. You can do it by getting a number that's too big, and then one that's too small (by trial and error, if you don't see a cleverer way), and then narrowing down the interval between them, by repeatedly looking at numbers halfway in between. A more efficient, Calculus-based technique is called *Newton's Method*, which see.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation#General_cubic_formula

Comment: Okay, I thought I was missing some algebra factoring technique to solve this in a clever way but this is just a matter of typing the formula in a graphing calculator and getting a results back. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If I may suggest, avoid truncating mathematical constants up to the end of the calculations since you never know in advance what could be its impact on the result.

Let me consider the equation
$$2\pi_{(n)}=3+2t-0.1t^3$$ where $\pi_{(n)}=10^{-n} \text{Round}\left[\pi \times 10^n\right]$. Below are the the roots as a function of $n$
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & t_1 & t_2 & t_3 \\
 0 &  -5.08875& 1.78380& 3.30495 \\
 1 &  -5.12311& 2.00000& 3.12311 \\
 2 &  -5.13668& 2.10909& 3.02759 \\
 3 &  -5.13735& 2.11513& 3.02222 \\
 4 &  -5.13722& 2.11392& 3.02330 \\
 5 &  -5.13721& 2.11389& 3.02333 \\
 6 &  -5.13722& 2.11390& 3.02332 
\end{array}
\right) $$

May be, you could prefer the exact result obtained by the trigonometric for three real roots (have a look at the Wikipedia page)
$$t =-4 \sqrt{\frac{5}{3}} \cos \left(\frac{2 \pi  k}{3}-\frac{1}{3} \cos
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{3}{8} \sqrt{\frac{3}{5}} (3-2 \pi )\right)\right) \qquad \text{with} \qquad k=0,1,2$$ and round the results ?